# What is a simple way to read an input that can be either an integer or a character?

Tags: java

Since there is no way to call nextChar(), I am not sure how I am supposed to read an input which could either be 2 integers (separated by a white space) or a character. Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, instead of `if (next=="q")`  use `if (next.equals("q"))` to compare strings. Note that even though `"q"` is a single character, it's still a `String` object. You could use `next.charAt(0)` to get the `char` `'q'`, and then, you could indeed use `next == 'q'`.

Also, instead of `next()` use `nextLine()`, and if the user didn't type `"q"`, split the line to get the two integers. Otherwise, if you call `next()` two times, and you just type `"q"`, you'll never exit the program, since the scanner will wait for the user to type something to return from the second `next()`:

```
String next = keyboard.nextLine();
if (next.equals("q")) {
  System.out.println("You are a quitter. Goodbye.");
}
else {
  String[] pair = next.split(" ");
  int r = Integer.valueOf(pair[0]);
  int c = Integer.valueOf(pair[1]);
  System.out.printf("%d %d\n", r, c);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use `next.equals("q")` instead. `==` should generally be used only on primitives. Try this:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a coordinate [row col] or press [q] to quit: ");
String next = keyboard.nextLine();

if (next.equals("q")){  // You can also use equalsIgnoreCase("q") to allow for both "q" and "Q".
    System.out.println("You are a quitter. Goodbye.");
    isRunning=false;
}
else {
    String[] input = next.split(" ");
    // if (input.length != 2) do_something (optional of course)
    int r = Integer.parseInt(pair[0]);
    int c = Integer.parseInt(pair[1]);
    // possibly catch NumberFormatException...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

String comparison should be

```
"q".equals(next)
```

`==` compares two references pointing to same object or not. Generally used for primitives comparison.

`.equals()` compares values objects have to determine equality.